# Vue input deleteContentBackward get deleted character?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When typing in an input field and forwarding `@input = 'func'`, that function recieves an object containing among other things `data` and `inputType`.

When inputType is `deleteContentBackward` is there a Vue built-in way of getting that removed character? Because data is then null.

It's solveable otherwise, just wondering if there is a built-in place where it is registered.

Comment: I do not think so, what you can do is, do not have v-model rather assign any input value to a variable after validation checks so that you always compare the input to the previous input. In a case where there was a previous input and not there is none you can know for a fact there was a backspcae.

Comment: Note we already know backspace was pressed when `e.inputType is 'deleteContentBackward'`. Thanks for your comment.